# Downloading PSSM file from NCBI PSI-Blast results after the UI update

Tags: phylogenetics, psi-blast, pssm

It used to be easy to download off a results page of a PSI-Blast from NCBI the PSSM (scorematrix). Now I cannot seem to find an `asn` file that is a scorematrix —`Download>ASN.1` is the output of the search. Whereas before it was in "format results" IIRC.
I was after this to check something in the PSSM viewer or do further cycles of PSI-Blast with different settings —the latter especially handy given that at present the exclude taxa checkbox is troublesome. Where is the option gone?
[image]

Comment: Addendum: a blast search with only excluded taxa never used to glitched but now does, but adding `biota` taxa prevents it from glitching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clicking on the "Back to Traditional Results Page" link in the top right corner? If you're expecting a different interface, that might help work out where to find the right information.

[image]